# Scale sceneView to fit screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, scenekit, aspect-ratio

I am developing a sample game using SceneKit and Swift in Xcode, I added a ship node (default) and add some animations. The problem is that the sceneView does not fit the screen because the aspect ratio does not seems to bee 16:9 as the screen of an average iPhone screen size. How can I scale the sceneView to fit the screen?

[image: Here is how it looks]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the best way of solving this issue was to set the Launch Screen File = Main

[image: Just like this image shows]

[image: And Now the scene looks like this:]